# how to restrict tab navigation control

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page having lot of selectable elements like `a`, `buttons`,`input` etc .when i press the tab the active elements becomes the next of the previous selected element ,thats ok but after the last element in dom the control goes th the address bar of the browser.how can i prevent this .

1. i have seen same implemented her in [stack](http://stackoverflow.com),jira etc.
2. i have tried giving tabindex (increasing order) to each element but not working.

does anybody have a solution ?please share .

Comment: tabIndex allows you to define the order in which elements inside the page are accessed, but it does not enable you to “trap” the user inside of the page. To do so, you will have to set an `onblur` listener on the last focusable element, and upon that reset focus to the first element. But as I said before, this could “trap” a user on the page – and for people using only this method of navigation it might be quite annoying.

Comment: @CBroe here am developing accounting app website that will be useful for fast navigation .thank you for the that info.i think i can delete my question now .

Comment: That’s fine, I just mentioned it because there’s always people who try and put that kind of stuff on “normal” websites and confuse users. And please don’t delete questions here, they might be helpful to others. Will add comment as an answer so that you can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tabIndex allows you to define the order in which elements inside the page are accessed, but it does not enable you to “trap” the user inside of the page.

To do so, you will have to set an onblur listener on the last focusable element, and upon that reset focus to the first element.

<del>But as I said before, this could “trap” a user on the page – and for people using only this method of navigation it might be quite annoying. (Warning considering public websites, not applicable for special cases.)</del>